# Where to initialize timber and crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, timber-android

My app do lot of background tasks and has few activities and most of the work is done in background.

Suppose I add timber and Crashlytics to my app. How can I make sure than when the app is updated on the device, timber, and Crashlytics get initialized without activity being opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update your app, it's always stopped and restarted - Timber and Crashlytics can be initialized at this moment.

When your application starts, method `onCreate()` of `android.app.Application` class is invoked. To add extra logic to this method, you need to create new MyApplication class, which extends `Application` class and override `onCreate()` method.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      //here initialize Timber and Crashlytics
   }
}
```

By default, `android.app.Application` class is used to initialize application context. Information about that another `Application` class is used should be provided in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myname.app">

    <application android:name="com.myname.MyApplication">
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```